# Why "activate cloud shell" opens a shell that is not what is under my newly created "Instance-1" virtual machine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terminal

I just set up everything on google cloud shell (terminal that activates when you press "activate cloud shell" on top right). However, i just now realised it is not the same thing as the Instance-1 i created as connecting to it by pressing "SSH" leaves me with none of the software i installed in google cloud shell.

Why is it so? Is it possible to add google cloud shell to the Instance-1 virtual machine i just created? (it would greatly easy software setup)

Comment: Cloudshell is not your actual VM, it is just an interactive tool to experiment and run your command lines. I would not recommend to install permanent information on cloudshell as they are ephemeral. https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs

Comment: If you want to make changes to your VM, from cloudshell you can [SSH](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) into your VM then make changes.

Comment: Cloud Shell runs in a container on a Google-managed virtual machine. Almost everything installed on a Cloud Shell instance can be installed in your virtual machine. Cloud Shell is just a nicely designed developer system to help you quickly get started in the cloud.

Comment: Is there an easy way to install basic software intomy instance-1 VM?

Comment: That depends on the OS and the software package. For Linux, there is apt and yum. Read the documentation for each software package for how to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @John hanley expressed in the comments, cloud shell are transient and it isn't suggested to utilize it to store or introduce lasting data and applications.

In your case, you'd like to have an instance where you've got a default setup with the fundamental software preinstalled. There are 3 alternatives you'll utilize for this situation.

Using Snapshot, Image or Instance template.

- A [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) reflects the contents of a persistent disk in a concrete
  instant in time. An image is the same thing, but includes an
  operating system and boot loader and can be used to boot an instance.
  But snapshot is cheaper in terms of cost.
- [Images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#prepare_instance_for_image) are primarily meant for boot disk creation. They optimized for
  multiple downloads of the same data over and over. If the same image
  is downloaded many times, subsequent to the first download the following
  downloads are going to be very fast (even for large images).
- [Instance templates](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates) define the machine type, boot disk image or
  container image, labels, and other instance properties. An instance
  template is a global resource that is not bound to a zone or a region.

All these options can create an instance using the cloud shell and you can get the command line version by clicking the [Equivalent command line](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/running-gcloud-commands) button when creating the resource.

After the setup, you will just initiate the command on cloud shell based on the option you chose then connect to your instance via [SSH](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) from cloud shell as also suggested by @dany L.